# server,php file missing, fatal error

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-artisan

I have been using laravel for multiple projects already, however for some reason my new laravel project does not have the server.php file.

Reinstalling composer and / or recreating the project does not work. I also can't put a file by the name of server.php into the project in any way.

> [Fri May 11 02:26:55 2018] PHP Warning:  Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
>   [Fri May 11 02:26:55 2018] PHP Fatal error:  Unknown: Failed opening required 'C:\Users\Luke Derkzen\Documents\GitHub\Website\server.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in Unknown on line 0

I get this error when I try to start the server, as far as I can see it's expecting me to have something running on XAMPP, however on my other projects there is a server.php file, and it doesn't give above error.

The project was created with following command:

> composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel

If i use the php artisan serve command afterwards to start the server and reload the page. above error appears in the artisan console.

How can I fix this?

Comment: How are you _"starting the server"_?

Comment: You can just copy that server.php file from the other project and place it on that new project. The server.php file is the same on every project.

Comment: @RBCunhaDesign doesn't really answer the question though

Comment: @Phil with the php artisan serve command

Comment: @RBCunhaDesign I can't create or copy a file called server.php into the new project.

Comment: @LukeDerkzen please add to your questions **all the steps** required to reproduce the problem, in detail

Comment: @Phil I don't know how to reproduce it myself seeing as this never happened before doing the same thing. I did specify how the project was created though, if that is enough.

Comment: _"I don't know how to reproduce it myself"_ <- so you _don't_ have a problem anymore?

Comment: @Phil, Yes I do, but all I can say is the command i wrote in my question and the little bit of text I just added below it. I don't know what else to give you...

Comment: What **exactly** is the _"php artisan serve command"_? Are you saying that all you run is `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel` and then the _"php artisan serve command"_ and you get the error?

Comment: @Phil correct. If I'm not mistaken that's all that should be done according to laravels own documentation

Comment: @LukeDerkzen I don't use xamp, but I would suggest checking your php/xamp installation and file permissions. BTW if your permissions are fine, than why can't you copy server.php to your new project? That's why I believe, you have some problems with file/dir permissions....

Comment: @Bart I do have issues with the permissions, but no matter what I change I can;t place a server.php file in that folder. And I also have never used xampp before for laravel.

Comment: @LukeDerkzen learn more about windows permissions for example here https://superuser.com/questions/33373/how-do-i-get-permissions-to-save-in-a-folder-that-windows-7-denies-me-from

Comment: @Bart even if I copy the file using an administrator command prompt it says Access is denied. And according to the windows security tab I have full access on everything.

Comment: @Luke you may need to inspect this folder, sometimes admin is not enough. Either way I would check and fix your windows installation asap. Last thing I could suggest is to put your website in folder where you have really full access...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occured, as rightly predicted by some, due to corrupt windows permissions. I talked about it with microsoft support, however they could offer no solution (without paying $50 / $150) so I did a clean install of windows.

While I'm sure this isn't a solution people hope to find, it was the only way for me.

Answer (score 9):

Server.php make a **Exception** and your **Anti-Virus** like Avast delete it Automatically. Make turn off your **Anti-VIrus** Software.

Comment: Yes, same my case 

AVG antivirus delete server.php and protected cannot create the file, I have to turn off File Shield and copy file server.php from another project

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have another project from where to copy the server.php file, go to this GitHub link (https://github.com/digitalocean/sample-laravel/blob/main/server.php), copy the code and create a server.php file and put the code there. create the file in your project or app root directory.